# Law of total variance and feature selection

Tags: variance, feature-selection

According to the law of total variance, the variance of the expected value of an estimator conditioned on some other RV is at least as small as the variance of the original estimator.

Does this relate to feature selection? If we remove a feature, we are effectively not able to condition on it.  So, should we never remove features in order to minimize variance of the estimator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you predict $y$ by taking the conditional mean of it (with respect to one or both of the $x_i$s), then it will always be true that 
$$
\text{Var}[E(y \mid x_1)] \le \text{Var}[E(y \mid x_1, x_2)],
$$
by the law of total variance. Also, by the law of total expectation, each of these predictors will be "unbiased," so yes, the mean square prediction error will always be less when you condition on more variables.

However, this is all assuming you know the parameters. So that complicates this: with more predictors there is usually more parameter uncertainty.

Comment: Can you expand on the last statement?

Comment: @nan yeah I think that part is the more interesting question. It should probably get its own thread, though.